# Ubuntu 14.04 lockdown with Firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox, kiosk

I'm trying to create a lockdown environment for users where they can only use firefox and the allowed extensions.

I have managed to create a profile which causes that when uses log in, they only get to see firefox. They cannot open the settings or anything else with the mouse. They can however do this with the keyboard shortcuts. This is something I can disable with a simple plugin.

The problem however is that people need to be able to open dropdown menus on websites. With the curreny lockdown settings they can only move through the dropdown with the keyboard. When the dropdown is selected with the mouse, it will not open.

The file I'm using is /usr/share/xsessions/kiosk.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Kiosk Mode
Comment=Firefox Kiosk Mode
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox -height 900 -width 1440
Type=Application
```

Can someone please help to solve this problem?

To clarify:

The end result needs to be an environment in which the user automatically gets logged in on booting the system. When logged in, only firefox will be visible and no other applications or files can be shown or accessed. For one of the sites they will use additional hardware plugged into the laptop.

In Firefox they have the ability to visit sites(they will need the navigation bar) and use the plugins which are installed. They should not have access to the history, settings, printing or anything else.

Comment: How do you achieve "They cannot open the settings or anything else with the mouse"? That may be relevant to solve this question.

Comment: I think firefox might need something from Ubuntu to open these menu's and dropdowns. Because when I change the above script to open chromium-browser and remove the height and width option, everything works including menu and dropdown. The reason for not using Chromium is that firefox is easier to lock down with plugins. We do not want users to be able to access any files, history, settings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of further research, I came up with the [mkiosk addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/mkiosk/)

It has an option to show the navigation bar, you can set an admin password and you can achieve "no printing" by not installing [CUPS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/cups) at all:

```
sudo apt-get remove cups
```

In it's default setup, it has no admin password, so set up one. Also, you will need to change the home page to anything other than the default, in order to deny the access to the preferences, history etc. You can reach the mkiosk settings by hitting F1 on your keyboard and entering the admin password (the first time it does not have one).

I tested the addon fullscreen mode and that seems to work well. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Webconverger](http://webconverger.com), which does what you want to achieve. Webconverger is often used in enterprise kiosk setups.

Furthermore, it supports Flash so that the user can watch videos. On session termination, a new fresh session is started with the default settings as you set them.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. But I need to do this with Ubuntu and the users need to be able to use additional hardware for certain sites they need to use.